# Datapath#ports is kept for compatibility

Tags: python-2.7, ryu

I am trying to get ryu to run, especially the topology discovery.

Now I am running the demo application for that under `ryu/topology/dumper.py`, which is supposed to dump all topology events. I am in the `ryu/topology` direcory and run it using `ryu-manager dumper.py`. The version of ryu-manager is 2.23.2.

Shortly after starting it gives me this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/topology/switches.py:478: UserWarning:
 Datapath#ports is kept for compatibility with the previous openflow versions (< 1.3).
 This not be updated by EventOFPPortStatus message. If you want to be updated,
 you can use 'ryu.controller.dpset' or 'ryu.topology.switches'.
  for port in dp.ports.values():
```

What's really weird to me is that it recommends to use `ryu.topology.switches`, but that error is triggered by line 478 of that very file!

The function in question is this:

```
class Switches(app_manager.RyuApp):
    OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_0.OFP_VERSION, ofproto_v1_2.OFP_VERSION,
                    ofproto_v1_3.OFP_VERSION, ofproto_v1_4.OFP_VERSION]
    _EVENTS = [event.EventSwitchEnter, event.EventSwitchLeave,
               event.EventPortAdd, event.EventPortDelete,
               event.EventPortModify,
               event.EventLinkAdd, event.EventLinkDelete]

    DEFAULT_TTL = 120  # unused. ignored.
    LLDP_PACKET_LEN = len(LLDPPacket.lldp_packet(0, 0, DONTCARE_STR, 0))

    LLDP_SEND_GUARD = .05
    LLDP_SEND_PERIOD_PER_PORT = .9
    TIMEOUT_CHECK_PERIOD = 5.
    LINK_TIMEOUT = TIMEOUT_CHECK_PERIOD * 2
    LINK_LLDP_DROP = 5
#...
    def _register(self, dp):
        assert dp.id is not None

        self.dps[dp.id] = dp
        if dp.id not in self.port_state:
            self.port_state[dp.id] = PortState()
            for port in dp.ports.values():    # THIS LINE
                self.port_state[dp.id].add(port.port_no, port)
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem before? How can I fix it?

Comment: Let me know if the answer bellow helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue (depending on your application, maybe it's not a problem, just a warning that you can ignore). Here is what I figured out after a `find . -type f | xargs grep "ports is kept"`

This warning is triggered in `ryu.topology.switches`, by a call to `_get_ports()` in `class Datapath` of file `ryu/controller/controller.py`.

```
class Datapath(ofproto_protocol.ProtocolDesc):
    #......
    def _get_ports(self):
        if (self.ofproto_parser is not None and
                self.ofproto_parser.ofproto.OFP_VERSION >= 0x04):
            message = (
                'Datapath#ports is kept for compatibility with the previous '
                'openflow versions (< 1.3). '
                'This not be updated by EventOFPPortStatus message. '
                'If you want to be updated, you can use '
                '\'ryu.controller.dpset\' or \'ryu.topology.switches\'.'
            )
            warnings.warn(message, stacklevel=2)
        return self._ports

    def _set_ports(self, ports):
        self._ports = ports

    # To show warning when Datapath#ports is read
    ports = property(_get_ports, _set_ports)
```

My understanding is that if the warning is from `ryu.topology.switches` or `ryu.controller.dpset`, you can ignore it; because those two classes handle the event for you. But if you use `Datapath` directly, port status is not updated automatically. Anyone correct me if I'm wrong.

```
class Switches(app_manager.RyuApp):
    #......
    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPortStatus, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def port_status_handler(self, ev):
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered that problem before but I just ignored it and so far every thing has been working as it was expected.

If you are trying to learn the topology I would recommend using `ryu.topology.api`. i.e.

```
from ryu.topology.api import get_switch, get_link
```

There is this [tutorial](http://sdn-lab.com/2014/12/31/topology-discovery-with-ryu/). However there are some of the stuff missing.

Here is what I have so far:  [Controller.py](https://github.com/Ehsan70/RyuApps/blob/master/Controller.py)

In the [Controller.py](https://github.com/Ehsan70/RyuApps/blob/master/Controller.py) the two functions `get_switch(self, None)` and `get_link(self, None)` would give you list of links and switches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't test it right now. I will get back to you when I was able to test it out. Seems to be helpful!